# Arcade expression to calculate field in point dataset based on whether its features lie within specified polygon dataset using ArcGIS Pro ModelBuilder

Tags: arcgis-pro, field-calculator, modelbuilder, intersect, arcade

Can anyone help with an Arcade expression to calculate a new field in a point dataset based on whether or not each point feature is within a polygon dataset in ArcGIS Pro ModelBuilder?

I have a point dataset of CRM reports, and I want to indicate whether or not each point falls within the 1 in 100 year flood zone.

I am trying this in Calculate Field but it returns NULL values for each point. I also tried `$datastore` instead of `$map` but that didn't work either.

```
var point = Geometry($feature);
var polygon_layer = FeatureSetByName($map, 'flood');
var polygons = Intersects(polygon_layer, point);

if (Count(polygons) > 0) {
  return "yes";
}
else {
  return "no";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have tagged this question as ArcGIS Pro and mentioning ModelBuilder so it implies you are attempting this analysis in ArcGIS Pro and not in ArcGIS Online. If this is correct, you need to read the help file for the [Field calculate profile](https://developers.arcgis.com/arcade/profiles/field-calculation/). Under the profile variables it is very clear that `$map` is not an accessible variable to field calculations, so basically your approach is flawed and won't work. With that said I would say your approach is an unusual approach for computing the information you need. Typically I would be using the [Spatial join](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/analysis/spatial-join.htm) tool in ModelBuilder or possibly the new [Add Spatial Join](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/data-management/add-spatial-join.htm) tool.